# Get a result from thread function in a variable

Tags: python

```
def media_info():
    q = Queue()
    a1 = Thread(target=task_alexa, args=(q,)).start()
    a2 = Thread(target=task_crawl, args=(q,)).start()
    return {**a1, **a2}
```

the first thread return a json, the second one too.
I want to get the result of both of them in variable a1 and a2.
then i will merge them normaly.

Please help me: how can i get the result of a thread in one variable.

Thank you

Comment: At the time of your `return` statement, your Threads *don't* have a result yet - they possibly haven't even started executing yet.

Comment: Threads run asynchonously, that's the whole point. The `media_info()` function isn't waiting for the threads to complete.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join

Answer (score 0):

this is the correction

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def media_info():
    q = Queue()

    pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)

    a1 = pool.apply_async(task_alexa, (q,)) 
    a2 = pool.apply_async(task_crawl, (q,))

    r1 = a1.get()
    r2 = a2.get()

    return {**r1, **r2}
```